# how to get Class<X<T>> by guava TypeToken

Tags: java, guava, typetoken

There're two class, one named Service, the other named Domain.

```
class Domain<T> {
    String id;
    // some other common fields and methods
    T data;
    T getData() {
        return data;
    }

class Service<T> {
    T get(String id) {
        // here's we need a Class<Domain<T>> to do some work
        TypeToken<Domain<T>> typeToken = new TypeToken<Domain<T>>(getClass()){};
        // how to get `Class<Domain<T>>` from `typeToken` 
        Class<Domain<T>> = ...
    }
}
```

So, how to get `Class<Domain<T>>` from `TypeToken<Domain<T>>`?

Comment: There is no such thing as a `Class<X<T>>` - generics just don't work that way. The whole reason `TypeToken` exists is to workaround this limitation and allow you to refer to a generic type. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: @dimo414, in `Service#get` method, it ought to get the data which stores in mongodb. I was using spring's `MongoTemplate#findOne` method to retrieve the data from the db which method needs to passed the `Class<Domain<T>>` argument to deserialize the data. here's why i need a `Class<Domain<T>>`.

Answer (score 0):

*For the record, asking "How do I retrieve a generic type from [`MongoTemplate.findOne()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoTemplate.html#findOne-org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query-java.lang.Class-)?" would likely get you a [much better answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/147573).*

The `MongoTemplate` API doesn't accept `TypeToken` or any other generic-capturing mechanism. That means it doesn't safely support returning generic types. Assuming you know at compile-time what the type should be you can do an unsafe cast, however:

```
Domain<T> domain = (Domain<T>) template.findOne(query, Domain.class);
```

Notice that this passes in `Domain.class`, so `findOne()` will return a raw `Domain` instance, which then needs to be cast to `Domain<T>` to avoid working with a raw type.